# Passing String Parameters keeps quotes

Tags: bash, jenkins

I'm having a problem with bash/Jenkins where when I attempt to trigger a downstream build with parameters, and I call it like so:

in build 1:

-CURRENT_VAR is a string parameter of the current job

```
TEST_VAR=$CURRENT_VAR
```

and then in build 2:

```
echo "$TEST_VAR"
```

I get:

```
<contents of current $CURRENT_VAR>
```

which is exactly what I want.  The issue is, I don't want my build 1 to be parametrized and instead want to set the job parameters directly, like so:

```
TEST_VAR="Contents Here"
```

If I attempt this and call it, when I am in build 2 I get:

```
echo "$TEST_VAR"
"Contents Here"
```

with quotes and all.  When I attempt to concatenate it with other strings, the double quotes stay, and I'm left with a var looking like:

```
NewString="Leftside"$TEST_VAR"Rightside"
echo $NewString
```

or:

```
NewString="Leftside""$TEST_VAR""Rightside"
echo $NewString
```

I end up with

```
Leftside"Contents Here"Rightside
```

Is there any way to pass my constant string (for this particular job) into my downstream build without using a parameter for it and have it not show up with the quotes?  I have tried passing it with single quotes, but then it gets even more confusing and nightmareish (<'Content Here'> becomes <'\''Content Here'\''> and echoing results in <'Content Here'>)  Sorry for the verboseness, I'm not very familiar with bash.

Comment: This sounds like jenkins isn't using bash to parse those assignment lines (or something) because in a shell `TEST_VAR="Contents Here"` sets the contents of the `TEST_VAR` variable to `Contents Here` (no quotes). Does it work if you drop the quotes on that assignment line?

Comment: That... actually worked.  I would have never thought of that, I'm a SE student and that sounds like insanity to me, to create a string without quotes.  That did work though, so thank you very much!

Comment: That was mostly a guess based on the behavior of bash and what you were seeing. I don't actually know jenkins at all. Do they document the format of whatever file that assignment was in anywhere?

Comment: Not that I'm aware, I had done some pretty extensive looking but it was rather difficult to search.  God forbid earlier when I was attempting to sed out the '\', searching for that was simply impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like jenkins isn't using bash to parse those assignment lines (or something).

In bash `TEST_VAR="Contents Here"` sets the contents of the `TEST_VAR` variable to `Contents Here` (no quotes).

Try dropping the quotes on that assignment line.